# How to filter out "NA"?

Tags: excel, vba, filter

How to create a filter to make make button to NOT copy any rows in the range ,containing the string "NA".

```
Here is what I have so far:

Private Sub CommandButton4_Click()

  Application.ScreenUpdating = False
  Dim copySheet As Worksheet
  Dim pasteSheet As Worksheet

  Set copySheet = Worksheets("C")
  Set pasteSheet = Worksheets("Sheet1")

  copySheet.Range("A2:B20").Copy
  pasteSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).PasteSpecial 
 xlPasteValues
  Application.CutCopyMode = False
  Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: [An image of your code is not helpful](http://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode). • There is no attempt in your code to filter. Have you tried to use autofilter? • You can also try to use the macro recorder to get an idea how to use autofilter.

Comment: Is "NA" a real string, or an error, as Vlookup shows when no match has been found (`#N/A`). Then, should this 'string' exist only in one of the two columns (A:A and B:B)?

Comment: guys, i am a total vba beginner-just putting it out there. @FaneDuru yes "NA" is a string not an error. NA can be found only in A:A . I do not know how filter it out when copying. PLS HELP ! :D

Comment: You need to copy the code as text to your post which you can [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/71599382/edit) at any time.

Comment: Time to test my solution, I guess.

Comment: @VBasic2008 You solution transfers the whole sheet "C" into "Sheet1" and wipes everything from sheet "C".

Answer (score 1):

### Exclude Criteria Rows When Copying (`AutoFilter`)

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub CopyNonNA()
    
    Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook ' workbook containing this code
    
    Dim CopySheet As Worksheet: Set CopySheet = wb.Worksheets("C")
    
    Dim PasteSheet As Worksheet: Set PasteSheet = wb.Worksheets("Sheet1")
    Dim PasteCell As Range: Set PasteCell = PasteSheet _
        .Cells(PasteSheet.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Offset(1)
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    
    Dim CopyRange As Range
    
    With CopySheet
        If .FilterMode Then .ShowAllData
        With .Range("A1:B20")
            Dim drg As Range: Set drg = .Resize(.Rows.Count - 1).Offset(1)
            .AutoFilter 1, "<>NA"
            .AutoFilter 2, "<>NA"
             On Error Resume Next
                Set CopyRange = drg.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
            On Error GoTo 0
        End With
        .AutoFilterMode = False
    End With
    If CopyRange Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
    
    CopyRange.Copy
    PasteCell.PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    
    MsgBox "Values copied.", vbInformation
    
End Sub
```

Comment: This is the place to comment on my answer. I only now found in your comments this *NA can be found only in A:A* which is vital information and should be added to your post i.e. you should remove the line `.AutoFilter 2, "<>NA"` from the code which in the end shouldn't make any difference since it filters by `<>NA"`. In your code, you use 2 which means column `B` where you search for the last row. If this column is empty, it will paste the data to `B2:C20` minus the rows where it found `NA`. If that range covers your complete data, then everything will be wiped. Please clarify what is wiped.